# Ga4 To BigQuery Incomplete Data Transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

To use GA4 Data with BigQuery, I connected Them. the transfer process had no problem but after one month I see that the number of records and the storage of each table has reduced significantly (ex:400 mg turned to 600 kb).also my gcp account is a free version (no billing account connected). Still, I have checked that the storage of all tables didn't exceed the 10 G limit.
also, I just reconnected my GCP with big query but still have this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GA documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?hl=en#pricing&zippy=%2Cin-this-article), you need to have a valid billing ID to be able to export data to BQ.

- Check Cloud Logging to see if there are any failures during the BQ export. You can filter by the service account itself and increase the log range.
- Are you streaming or batch exporting the data?
- Please confirm the daily count of events; you can verify this directly from the property itself.
- Can you check your GCP quota page to see if you are reaching any limits?